# Object had not been disposed before I closed program

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am not good at English but I hope you understand what I say :) I'm trying to improve my skill.

Ok, I had some code like below:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int* p = new int();

    cin >> x; // waitting for user enter a integer number
    // BUT, what if the user force closes the program?

    cout << "The instructions from this to the end are not going to be run!" << endl;
    delete p;
    //..

    return 0;
}
```

The memory which was allocated by p pointer will never be disposed.

Do we have a solution for this problem?

THANKS :)

Updated:
Is it a memory leak?

Comment: Can you define what "force closes" means?

Comment: The OS will clean it up for you. It's an optimization to *not* clean up your memory when the process closes because it's going to be freed anyway. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx

Comment: "will never be disposed" that's not true, the operating system will clean up any remaining resources.

Comment: Click to X button or Endprocess in Taskmanager that is what I mean. Am I wrong? :( Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any modern OS will manage it and clean up the whole memory that allocated by a process after closing it

Don't worry about that. You must worry about the memory when your program is running.

When your code is running. Avoid using bare pointers, try to use smart pointers if you need pointers.

Comment: I'll think about that :) Thanks.

Comment: So..Is it Memory leaks?

Comment: Yes, but when your code is immediately closing, after that OS will clean up the whole memory of your process.

Comment: Why do we should use Delete function like "int *p = new int; //do something//; delete p"? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The operating system will take care of this.
It will free all memory (and also other resources like sockets) that were allocated by the program after the program finishes.

Answer (score 1):

A `SIGKILL`, or the Windows equivalent of that, will close the program without cleanup occurring. The OS will reclaim memory and resources like file descriptors/file handles. There's very little you can do about that; "hard kill" signals exist as a last resort for programs that will not terminate voluntarily.

Some other "soft kill" signals can be [caught](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) and handled appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you take Windows, for instance, then closing the console window will force-close your application.

All memory and OS-handles that your program has allocated will be freed by the OS itself, so that is not something that you need to worry about. One cannot 'protect' against all possible forced application terminations.

You should make a program that under normal conditions leaks no memories, and if using exceptions then does not leak when an exception is thrown.